# Image from sd-card is not loaded in webview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I want to Send some `HTML` code from `MainActivity` to a `WebViewActivity` which have a `WebView` layout, I want to get the `HTML`  code and display image on `webview` .
My `HTML` code is :

```
<html><img alt=\"myImagenotshowing\" src=\"file://mnt/sdcard/HappyEnding.jpg\"></html>
```

And My `WebViewActivity` is :

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static String TAG = "WebViewActivity";
private WebView webView;
public static final String MY_EXTRA = "fulltext";   

Bundle extras;
String value;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    value = getIntent().getStringExtra(MY_EXTRA);// Here it gets HTML code that I want to display inwebview
    Log.w(MY_EXTRA, "Data recieved is >> " + value);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);       

    // Makes Progress bar Visible
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
            Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {             

            view.loadData(value, "text/html", null);
            return true;
        }
    });

    new GetData().execute(null, null, null);        

}


private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(
                false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(
                WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(200);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        // webView.clearHistory();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        webView.loadData(value, "text/html", null);
    }

}}
```

the above code does not display image from `/mnt/sdcard/HappyEnding.jpg`.
How to fix that..

`CODE` this is my code sent from `MainActivity`:

```
String value2 = "<html><img alt=\"myImagenotshowing\" src=\"file://mnt/sdcard/HappyEnding.jpg\"></html>";
intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,  WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MY_EXTRA, value2);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: did you get solution ? could you pls share it here if you succeed with that?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVe Oh Man! sorry but I couldn't figure out that I solved that issue or not because it is three year old. Can't you find any solution on the net?? I' hope with some tries you would find a solution regarding your issue.

Answer (score 1):

show images in webview Read src from sd card

```
 <img style="width:100%"  src="file:///mnt/sdcard/ax.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<html><img alt=\"myImagenotshowing\" src=\"file://mnt/sdcard/HappyEnding.jpg\"></html>
```

or

```
String name = "/K/test.jpg";
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
String imagePath = "file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + name;
String html = "<html><head></head><body><center><img src=\"" + imagePath + "\"></center></body></html>";
webv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

add this permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Edited:
**Here is Full code of your answer :**  Its working find now.

```
package com.example.testbrowser;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static String TAG = "WebViewActivity";
    private WebView webView;
    private String value;
    public static final String MY_EXTRA = "fulltext";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light);

        // value = getIntent().getStringExtra(MY_EXTRA);
        value = "<html><img alt='myImagenotshowing' src='file://mnt/sdcard/abc.jpg'></html>";
        Log.e(MY_EXTRA, "Data recieved is >> " + value);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Makes Progress bar Visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        // webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", value, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {             

                view.loadDataWithBaseURL("", value, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
                return true;
            }
        });

        new GetData().execute(null, null, null);
    }

    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(
                    false);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(
                    WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
            webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(200);
            webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            webView.clearCache(true);
            // webView.clearHistory();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", value, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Dear! I have tried this but it say's `Web Console(610): Not allowed to load local resource: file://mnt/sdcard/HappyEnding.jpg at :0`

Comment: n before that you have added permission "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />" ??

Comment: Yes `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ` is already added.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ??????

Comment: Now I have added this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ` but still my try is unsuccessful..!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25828/discussion-between-dhaval-sodha-parmar-and-arshad-ali-arshay)

Answer (score 0):

After search, i found that the solution is easier than Wasting 1 hours of search.
Use   wbView.loadDataWithBaseURL() instead of wbView.loadData()

```
webv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```